# How to save (or) keep Global login credentials for 10 days in windows mobile application, after closing the application?

Tags: uwp, windows-mobile

currently am working on global variables.am saving the login details in global variable app.xaml.cs in my windows mobile application.I just want to keep the login details for a long time even after logout or closes the application.i want to store the data for long time. Is it possible ? can anyone give me idea for my problem.

```js
//app.xaml.cs
public string username { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }

//navigate to next page
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(new page name), null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can simply create a local file in App folder and persist data in it even if App is closed using UWP classes below -

```
// Create sample file; replace if exists.

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
    await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt",
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Your data");
```

You can simply delete a file using `DeleteAsync` method whenever you want.

Also you can use `SQLLiteDb` in your app to store data in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use the [Credential Locker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker) to securely store and retrieve user credentials. Using the Credential Locker API, you can store the username and password for your user and easily retrieve them and log the user in automatically the next time they open your app. Then, you could set a time stamp in [localsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) when you use Credential Locker to save credentials.

You could first check the time stamp if it's 10 days overdue when you retrieve credentials from Credential Locker. If it's out of date, you could remove it from Credential Locker and require user to input their username and password again.

Here's a [Credential Locker](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/PasswordVault) sample for your details.